# Round Image Link

Tags: asp.net, image, hyperlink

I am building a website and I'd like to add a link to a facebook page.
Designer has sent me a round image to represent the facebook link. Actually, the image is a rectangle, but the painting is round.
What I want is the pointer to change to the "link hand" only when over the round area of the image.
I could partially achieve that with this:

```
.imgFacebook {    
    border-radius:50%;
    height:50px;    
}
```

However the result I'm getting is: it is working for the image's top-side. In the top side, when I move the mouse outside the round, pointer gets back to an arrow.
The bottom side is still considering the image as a square image and changing the pointer outside the round design to a "hand", representing a link.
I have tried to set the border radius individually for each corner (top-left/right and bottom left/right), with no success.
So, does anyone knows how can I get a round area in my image as a link?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After some searches using different keywords, I was able to find a "how to" in this link.
http://jsfiddle.net/6UYTL/2/
I just had to add the image inside the div. As for the image I have used some style to make it display round as well.

```
<a href="http://www.wherelionsroam.co.uk" target="_blank">
    <div id="a">
        <asp:Image ID="imgLinkFacebook" runat="server" CssClass="imgFacebook"/>
    </div>
</a>

.imgFacebook {    
    border-radius:50%;
    height:50px;    
}
```

Thanks anyway.